# How to iterate and apply conditions to pandas columns, and store the results in a new column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follow:

| mea1 | mea2 | mea3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.38 | 0.11 | 0.02 |
| 0.32 | 0.12 | 0.03 |

I would like to check each row in the columns for the below conditions and store the results (0 or 1) in a new column called FC.

If mea1 is between 0.3 and 0.4 then FC = 1, else 0

If mea2 is between 0.10 and 0.11 and FC != 0, then FC = 1, else 0

If mea3 is between 0.01 and 0.05 and FC != 0, then FC = 1, else 0

Result: (1): met and (0): failed

| mea1 | mea2 | mea3 | FC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.38 (1) | 0.11 (1) | 0.02 (1) | 1 |
| 0.32 (1) | 0.12 (0) | 0.03 (1) | 0 |

I was able to achieve the result by using nested for-loops but the program took forever to run on a table with 10,000+ entries.

Here is my latest attempt at using the lambda function without checking for FC. col = mea1 etc...:

`df['FC'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if ((x[x[col] >= lower_limit]) & (x[x[col] <= upper_limit])) else 0 , axis = 1 )`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
df['FC'] = (
             (df['mea1'] >=0.3) & (df['mea1'] <= 0.4)
             & (df['mea2'] >= 0.1) & (df['mea2'] <= 0.11) 
             & (df['mea3']>=0.01) & (df['mea3']<=0.05)
          ) * 1
```

Comment: I think `.astype(int)` is more clear on what's happening than `* 1`, but this would still be a feasible answer.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I used BeRT2me's solution but I think it's similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

"Iteration" and pandas don't really mix. If you think the only way to do what you're thinking of doing is through iteration, you're probably wrong. Most of the time there is a fast, vectorized, solution.

```
df['FC'] = (df.mea1.between(0.3, 0.4, inclusive='both')
           & df.mea2.between(0.1, 0.11, inclusive='both')
           & df.mea3.between(0.01, 0.05, inclusive='both')).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   mea1  mea2  mea3  FC
0  0.38  0.11  0.02   1
1  0.32  0.12  0.03   0
```

Comment: Thank you! I started with your solution and modified the code a bit and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

```
def assignFC(row: pd.Series):
    fc = 0
    if row[“mea1”] >= 0.3 and row[“mea1”] <= 0.4:
        fc = 1
    if row[“mea2”] >= 0.1 and row[“mea2”] <= 0.11 and fc==1:
        fc = 1
    else:
        fc = 0
    if row[“mea3”] >= 0.01 and row[“mea3”] <= 0.05 and fc==1:
        fc = 1
    else:
        fc = 0
    return fc

df[“FC”] = df.apply(assignFC, axis=1)
```